# android- how to create tomorrow date via Date class

Tags: android, android-date

I want to make tomorrow date via Date class , this is my code for making today's date :

```
 persianDatePicker.setDisplayDate(new Date());
```

how can I make tomorrow date via Date class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        Date tomorrow=calendar.getTime();
persianDatePicker.setDisplayDate(tomorrow);
```